# read xml file and output to csv with specific fields

Tags: python, xml, formatting

I am trying to format the nvd cve xml files into a csv file for validation testing

here is a excerpt from the xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<all>
    <CVE_data_type type="str">CVE</CVE_data_type>
    <CVE_data_format type="str">MITRE</CVE_data_format>
    <CVE_data_version type="str">4.0</CVE_data_version>
    <CVE_data_numberOfCVEs type="str">6418</CVE_data_numberOfCVEs>
    <CVE_data_timestamp type="str">2020-01-26T08:30Z</CVE_data_timestamp>
    <CVE_Items type="list">
        <item type="dict">
            <cve type="dict">
                <data_type type="str">CVE</data_type>
                <data_format type="str">MITRE</data_format>
                <data_version type="str">4.0</data_version>
                <CVE_data_meta type="dict">
                    <ID type="str">CVE-2013-0001</ID>
                    <ASSIGNER type="str">cve@mitre.org</ASSIGNER>
                </CVE_data_meta>
                <problemtype type="dict">
                    <problemtype_data type="list">
                        <item type="dict">
                            <description type="list">
                                <item type="dict">
                                    <lang type="str">en</lang>
                                    <value type="str">CWE-200</value>
                                </item>
                            </description>
                        </item>
                    </problemtype_data>
                </problemtype>
                <references type="dict">
                    <reference_data type="list">
                        <item type="dict">
                            <url type="str">
                                https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/security-updates/securitybulletins/2013/ms13-004
                            </url>
                            <name type="str">MS13-004</name>
                            <refsource type="str">MS</refsource>
                            <tags type="list"/>
                        </item>
                        <item type="dict">
                            <url type="str">
                                https://oval.cisecurity.org/repository/search/definition/oval%3Aorg.mitre.oval%3Adef%3A15814
                            </url>
                            <name type="str">oval:org.mitre.oval:def:15814</name>
                            <refsource type="str">OVAL</refsource>
                            <tags type="list"/>
                        </item>
                    </reference_data>
                </references>
                <description type="dict">
                    <description_data type="list">
                        <item type="dict">
                            <lang type="str">en</lang>
                            <value type="str">The Windows Forms (aka WinForms) component in Microsoft .NET Framework 1.0
                                SP3, 1.1 SP1, 2.0 SP2, 3.0 SP2, 4, and 4.5 does not properly initialize memory arrays,
                                which allows remote attackers to obtain sensitive information via (1) a crafted XAML
                                browser application (XBAP) or (2) a crafted .NET Framework application that leverages a
                                pointer to an unmanaged memory location, aka &quot;System Drawing Information Disclosure
                                Vulnerability.&quot;
                            </value>
                        </item>
                        <item type="dict">
                            <lang type="str">en</lang>
                            <value type="str">Per http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bulletin/ms13-004
                                Microsoft .NET Framework 3.0 Service Pack 2 is not vulnerable.
                            </value>
                        </item>
                    </description_data>
                </description>
            </cve>
            <configurations type="dict">
                <CVE_data_version type="str">4.0</CVE_data_version>
                <nodes type="list">
                    <item type="dict">
                        <operator type="str">AND</operator>
                        <children type="list">
                            <item type="dict">
                                <operator type="str">OR</operator>
                                <cpe_match type="list">
                                    <item type="dict">
                                        <vulnerable type="bool">True</vulnerable>
                                        <cpe23Uri type="str">cpe:2.3:a:microsoft:.net_framework:1.0:sp3:*:*:*:*:*:*
                                        </cpe23Uri>
                                    </item>
                                </cpe_match>
                            </item>
                            <item type="dict">
                                <operator type="str">OR</operator>
                                <cpe_match type="list">
                                    <item type="dict">
                                        <vulnerable type="bool">False</vulnerable>
                                        <cpe23Uri type="str">
                                            cpe:2.3:o:microsoft:windows_xp:-:sp3:media_center:*:*:*:*:*
                                        </cpe23Uri>
                                    </item>
                                    <item type="dict">
                                        <vulnerable type="bool">False</vulnerable>
                                        <cpe23Uri type="str">cpe:2.3:o:microsoft:windows_xp:-:sp3:tablet_pc:*:*:*:*:*
                                        </cpe23Uri>
                                    </item>
                                </cpe_match>
                            </item>
                        </children>
                    </item>
                    <item type="dict">
                        <operator type="str">AND</operator>
                        <children type="list">
                            <item type="dict">
                                <operator type="str">OR</operator>
                                <cpe_match type="list">
                                    <item type="dict">
                                        <vulnerable type="bool">True</vulnerable>
                                        <cpe23Uri type="str">cpe:2.3:a:microsoft:.net_framework:1.1:sp1:*:*:*:*:*:*
                                        </cpe23Uri>
                                    </item>
                                </cpe_match>
                            </item>
                            <item type="dict">
                                <operator type="str">OR</operator>
                                <cpe_match type="list">
                                    <item type="dict">
                                        <vulnerable type="bool">False</vulnerable>
                                        <cpe23Uri type="str">cpe:2.3:o:microsoft:windows_server_2003:*:sp2:*:*:*:*:*:*
                                        </cpe23Uri>
                                    </item>
                                    <item type="dict">
                                        <vulnerable type="bool">False</vulnerable>
                                        <cpe23Uri type="str">
                                            cpe:2.3:o:microsoft:windows_server_2008:*:sp2:x64:*:*:*:*:*
                                        </cpe23Uri>
                                    </item>
                                    <item type="dict">
                                        <vulnerable type="bool">False</vulnerable>
                                        <cpe23Uri type="str">
                                            cpe:2.3:o:microsoft:windows_server_2008:*:sp2:x86:*:*:*:*:*
                                        </cpe23Uri>
                                    </item>
                                    <item type="dict">
                                        <vulnerable type="bool">False</vulnerable>
                                        <cpe23Uri type="str">
                                            cpe:2.3:o:microsoft:windows_server_2008:-:sp2:itanium:*:*:*:*:*
                                        </cpe23Uri>
                                    </item>
                                    <item type="dict">
                                        <vulnerable type="bool">False</vulnerable>
                                        <cpe23Uri type="str">cpe:2.3:o:microsoft:windows_vista:*:sp2:x64:*:*:*:*:*
                                        </cpe23Uri>
                                    </item>
                                    <item type="dict">
                                        <vulnerable type="bool">False</vulnerable>
                                        <cpe23Uri type="str">cpe:2.3:o:microsoft:windows_vista:-:sp2:*:*:*:*:*:*
                                        </cpe23Uri>
                                    </item>
                                    <item type="dict">
                                        <vulnerable type="bool">False</vulnerable>
                                        <cpe23Uri type="str">cpe:2.3:o:microsoft:windows_xp:*:sp3:*:*:*:*:*:*</cpe23Uri>
                                    </item>
                                    <item type="dict">
                                        <vulnerable type="bool">False</vulnerable>
                                        <cpe23Uri type="str">cpe:2.3:o:microsoft:windows_xp:-:sp2:x64:*:*:*:*:*
                                        </cpe23Uri>
                                    </item>
                                </cpe_match>
```

i have so far been able to extract only a couple of the firelds as shown in the code below,

```py
import xmltodict

with open("nvd/nvdcve-1.1-2016.xml") as fd:
    doc = xmltodict.parse(fd.read())

    id = doc["all"]["CVE_Items"]["item"][0]["cve"]["CVE_data_meta"]["ID"]["#text"]
    desc = doc["all"]["CVE_Items"]["item"][0]["cve"]["description"]["description_data"][
        "item"
    ]["value"]["#text"]
    url = doc["all"]["CVE_Items"]["item"][0]["cve"]["references"]["reference_data"][
        "@list"
    ]["url"]
    v2complexity = doc["all"]["CVE_Items"]["item"][0]["cve"]["description"][
        "description_data"
    ]["item"]["value"]["#text"]
    v2vector = doc["all"]["CVE_Items"]["item"][0]["cve"]["description"][
        "description_data"
    ]["item"]["value"]["#text"]
```

when i get to the url i keep getting this error no matter how i tried to setup the key,

```
/usr/local/bin/python3.8 /Users/djobes/PycharmProjects/rainfall/read_xml-old.py Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "/Users/djobes/PycharmProjects/rainfall/read_xml-old.py", line 9, in <module> url = doc['all']['CVE_Items']['item'][0]['cve']['references']['reference_data']['@list']['url'] 
KeyError: '@list'
```

i went with XML to csv as oppsed to json, for almost the same error, index out of range.

Any help or pointers.

TIA

Comment: Is that what the XML actually looks like? Have you tried printing the result of `xmltodict.parse(fd.read())` to check if the contents are what you except? Also, is that the entire error message?

Comment: the whole error message is:                         /usr/local/bin/python3.8 /Users/djobes/PycharmProjects/rainfall/read_xml-old.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/djobes/PycharmProjects/rainfall/read_xml-old.py", line 9, in <module>
    url = doc['all']['CVE_Items']['item'][0]['cve']['references']['reference_data']['@list']['url']
KeyError: '@list'

Comment: I added it to your post, please check if the formatting is correct.

Comment: yep, i also fixed the xml file

Comment: By the way, `id` is already a builtin name in Python, you should probably change it.

Comment: That did it, i renamed the id field to cve_id, im  able to get the fields i need. But i was just told, that i need the json based file and not xml.

Comment: _But i was just told, that i need the json based file and not xml._ What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the

```py
id = doc["all"]["CVE_Items"]["item"][0]["cve"]["CVE_data_meta"]["ID"]["#text"]
```

to

```py
cve_id = doc["all"]["CVE_Items"]["item"][0]["cve"]["CVE_data_meta"]["ID"]["#text"]
```

let me index correctly, but i need to work off json file i was informed.